# what is happening in this simple double pointer example

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I have the following example code:

```
void doAlloc(int **p) {
  *p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
  **p = 80;
}

int main() {
  int *ptr2;
  doAlloc(&ptr2);
  printf("%d\n", *ptr2);
  free(ptr2);
}
```

If I understand correctly, `ptr2` is a pointer variable, and `&ptr2` is "address of" that pointer variable in memory.

My question is, since `doAlloc` accepts a double pointer `int **p` as parameter; I don't understand why `&ptr` is a `int **`.

I would expect something like this to be done instead:

```
int **ptr2;
doAlloc(ptr2);
```

How is the "address of" `ptr2` considered to be a valid value to pass as a double pointer?

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks.

Comment: because doAlloc gets a pointer to a pointer. A pointer itself - and not its value - is just like saying the address of.

Comment: its something usually done in C (to send address of) but i cant recall the reason, something with extra space

Comment: OT: In C it isn't necessary nor recommended to cast the results of `malloc/calloc/realloc`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/694576

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simply, if you have

```
int a;
```

then

```
&a
```

Is of type `int*`

In your case, you have to consider an extra pointer for all your occurrences.

Comment: So I have `int *ptr2`, therefore `&ptr2` is a `int **`, correct?

Comment: @RobertHume Yes, it's really that simple.

Comment: Can you briefly explain why doAlloc can't just accept the original `int *ptr2` as an argument?  Why does it have to be a `int **` ?

Comment: @RobertHume This is explained well in Arkku answer

Comment: http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~wolber/SoftwareDev/C/paramPassing.htm this might show a real usage

Comment: Thanks -- your simple answer was the simple piece of info my brain was missing. :)

Answer (score 0):

`&ptr2` is the address of `ptr2`.

Since `pt2r` is a pointer to an integer

`&ptr2` is a pointer to a pointer to an integer:

```
int ** ptr2;
```

If it may help unserstandig the code above is equivalent to:

```
int  *doAlloc() {
  int *p;
  p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
  *p = 80;
  return p; 
}

int main(void) {
  int *ptr2;
  ptr2 = doAlloc();
  printf("%d\n", *ptr2);
  free(ptr2);
}
```

Comment: Is there a return statement missing in your doAlloc?

Comment: If there was a return line, would it be ... `return &p` ?

Comment: do you mean if it was generated by the compiler? maybe

Comment: @Infested: Not returning anything from a non void function provokes undefined behaviour. Also @Paolo: In C it isn't necessary nor recommended to cast the results of `malloc/calloc/realloc`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/694576

Comment: @alk thats what i said - maybe and perhaps.

Comment: @Infested: "*some compilers will add a return line*" I heavily doubt this.

Comment: @alk well, i can tell you they do.

Comment: @RobertHume: `return p;` is missing.

Comment: @Infested: How would they know what to return?

Comment: @alk some compilers are smarter than some ;)

Comment: @Infested: Which are the smarter ones please? Btw: If it's to be considered "smarter" not complying to the C-Standard is matter to discuss.

Comment: @alk VS, sometimes ubuntu will also generate it.

Comment: @Robert Hume: yes, return p was missing, thanks to alk to fix my code. AFAIK compilers won't add a return line. Some IDEs would show a warning as the function is not void but end without returning anything.

Comment: @Infested: Hu, I didn't knew ubuntu is a compiler. And as far as I know VS is an IDE.

Comment: @alk youre right, not the ubuntu - a compiler in ubuntu for c/c++ files.

Comment: @Infested: Ah I see, which compiler, please (name, version)?

Comment: @alk im not that into this, i just know it works like this on some.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is an address to a variable. The type of `ptr2` is `int *` (pointer to int), i.e., it contains the address of an int. The argument of `doAlloc` is of type `int **` (pointer to pointer to int), i.e., it contains the address of a pointer to int. Passing `&ptr2` passes the address of `ptr2`, and since `ptr2` is a pointer to int (`int *`), its address is of the correct type (`int **`).

(The reason why a pointer to pointer is required here is because `doAlloc` wants to modify the `ptr2` pointer of `main`, not just the `int` it points to. A way to do it without the pointer to pointer would be to have `doAlloc` return a pointer to the allocated memory—then it would be the responsibility of the caller to assign it to a pointer.)

Comment: Very helpful, thanks!  Antonio's answer helped me figure it out conceptually, and now I understand your answer too. :)

Answer (score 0):

A pointer in 'C' - yes - points to a memory location, where to store data (lets not talk about the type of, for now)

so let us assume: you do something like this (I try to go from the basics):

```
 int *p = 70;
 *p=65;
```

then you have your 'p' pointing to the address #70 (this is my syntax here for now thinking in 8-bit bytes no modern CPU architeckture), and then you assign '65' to where your 'p' points -> #70, so how looks the memory?

```
#6e ---
#6f ---
#70 65
#71 ---
```

so where is your 'p'?

```
#2212 --- here starts the stack
#2213 70 // p! 
#2214 --
```

and then you call: `doAlloc(&ptr2);`

that means: doAlloc get the address of 'p' ergo: 2213 and then it puts (a new alocated buffer address(!) there - into that 2213 - lets say '96'

```
#2212 --- here starts the stack
#2213 96 // p! new address of buffer 
#2213 --
```

and then you put '80' where this thing points to: 96 ... `**p = 80;`

```
#68 ---
#69 ---
#70 65
#71 ---
...
#94 ---
#95 ---
#96 80
#97 ---
```

I hope to point out what *basicaly* happens you could (theoretically) write

```
void doAlloc(int *p) {
  p = (int)malloc(sizeof(int));
  *p = 80;
}
```

so leave all the 2nd '*' alone

the compiler will tell you that it is wrong (and it is!), but that is what happens